# Effects and animations with Google Maps markers

Tags: html, google-maps, animation, google-maps-api-3, html5-canvas

I would like to know how to create effects / animations over Google Maps markers. Specifically, I would like to zoom-in/out or "fade" a marker after a given amount of time. Could it be possible with HTML5 ? Is there any jquery effect library for doing this?

(I could use a map tile server for creating map tile overlays and re-generate tile overlays every second, but I guess it is very processing-intensive...)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't seen any library to do this, and there isn't functionality in the API to fade Markers per say.

Instead, what you can do is simulate markers by creating your own [Custom Overlay](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#CustomOverlays) that looks like a marker.  A custom overlay usually contains a div, which you can easily control the opacity of using JavaScript / jQuery based on a class or id you assign during the custom overlay construction.

As an example, if you look at [this](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-hideshow.html) page you can see the is a button used to toggle the visibility, you could just as easily change that JavaScript to control the opacity of something.

Answer (score 2):

I am looking at doing something similar.
If you set the marker option 'optimized: false' for all markers, each will have its own element, you can then use jQuery to select all the markers on your map using something along the lines of $('#map_canvas img[src*="filename"]'), assuming that you're using custom images for the markers.

What this doesn't address is relating each element in the array returned to a specific marker.
I think that you could add the markers to the map one at a time, re-run the jquery selector, and compare the elements returned vs. the previous run, to see which element was new. I haven't tested this part (I have what I say in the first paragraph), as I'm working towards something slightly different.

You should then be able to adjust the opacity/size of the image directly.
This might get clunky for large numbers of markers.

---

Paragraph two above is stupid.

Add a marker to the map, making sure to set the optimized:false option. then

```
var freshlyAddedMarkerImage = $('#map_canvas img[src*="your_marker_icon"][class!="adjustMe"]');
```

The newly added marker won't have the class, so will be the only element selected. Before setting the className, you could set an ID, add the element to an array in the same index position as the corresponding marker object is held in another array, etc.

This should be a lot less clunky to implement than what I proposed previously. I'll try and come back with a working example soon.

I suppose if you knew that there were groups of markers that would share the same transform (zoom/fade), due to being the same age or whatever, then you could add all of them and only do the jQuery select at the end, before looping through the returned elements setting a class that would allow you to adjust them en-masse.