# How to control google map markers' opacity

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I need to make some markers semi-transparent depending on time. Is there any way to control the CSS opacity of a marker? Or is it possible to reliably find out a marker's DOM element?

I use Google Maps API v3.

Comment: This is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721327/effects-and-animations-with-google-maps-markers/8722970#8722970

Comment: See the answer about marker.setOpacity - it is the correct way now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way via CSS.  You could reference the markers in an array, and then loop through the array using the `setIcon()` method on each marker object to reference icons with different opacities (presuming you're using PNGs with alpha transparency).  You'll have to call a function to change the icons based on user input or some other event.

Comment: It would be great to add the way how the opacity is actually changed in a code snippet.

Answer (score 38):

The opacity of markers can be set with `marker.setOptions({'opacity': 0.5})`

Answer (score 20):

You can use `marker.setOpacity(0.5);`
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Marker

**code snippet:**

```js
var marker;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: {
        lat: -33.9,
        lng: 151.2
      },
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: -33.890542,
      lng: 151.274856
    },
    map: map,
    title: "Bondi Beach"
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input id="inc" type="text" value="0.5" />
<input type="button" id="set" value="set opacity" onclick="marker.setOpacity(parseFloat(document.getElementById('inc').value))" />
<input type="button" id="full" value="full opacity" onclick="marker.setOpacity(1.0);" />
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the opacity when you create the marker

```
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({opacity:0.5, ...});
```