# Google Maps Marker Set Opacity With Transition

Tags: google-maps

Based on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32114337/2524631) I see it is possible to set opacity to a marker. Does anyone know if one can add a transition property as well so that the transition to, let's say opacity 0.7, happens at a duration of `350ms`? I have tried adding the following css keys to the method `setOptions`:

```
marker.setOptions({'opacity': 0.7, 'transition-property': 'opacity', 'transition-duration': '350ms'})
```

But the transition duration does not seem to be working. The marker's opacity just changes immediately.

Comment: You could use a custom overlay instead of a Marker.

Comment: Right now I am using a custom icon as allowed here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#MarkerOptions.icon -- what do you mean by a custom overlay?

Comment: That syntax only lets you set **defined** [MarkerOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#MarkerOptions).  `transition-propery` and `transition-duration` are not valid MarkerOptions (so they will be ignored).

Comment: You can implement `OverlayView` to create a custom HTML marker. The docs has examples of [custom overlay](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple) implementation. Then you can use plain HTML and CSS to construct your markers.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **setTimeout** at 350 ms to set the marker's opacity to 0.7 .

```
  setTimeout(function(){ 
  marker.setOpacity(0.7);
  }, 350);
```

Here is a [sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/e5pr72qf/).